# Write value only once in CSV using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having the below code to write the data to csv

```
$myVMs = @(Get-VM -Server $vc | where {$_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn'} | select -Unique)        
        foreach ($myVM in $myVMs){        
         
            $VMDKs = $myVM | get-HardDisk
            $VMDISKMode = $myVM
            foreach ($VMDK in $VMDKs) {
                if ($VMDK -ne $null){
                $Diskmode = $VMDK.Persistence
                     if($Diskmode -ne 'Persistent')
                      {
                    $Report = [PSCustomObject] @{
                            Name = $myVM.name 
                            Server = $vc
                            PowerState = $myVM.PowerState
                            Disk = $VMDK.Name
                            DiskMode = $VMDK.Persistence
                        }
                    $Report | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $File -Append
                      }                          
                    }   
                }                
            }            
        }
```

the output i am getting

```
Name                Server          PowerState  Disk           DiskMode
171_A92SV095    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 6    IndependentPersistent
171_A92SV095    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 7    IndependentPersistent
171_A92SV095    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 8    IndependentPersistent
171_A92SV095    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 10   IndependentPersistent
171_A92SV096    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 5    IndependentPersistent
171_A92SV096    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 10   IndependentPersistent
```

want the data like below

```
Name                Server          PowerState  Disk           DiskMode
171_A92SV095    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 6    IndependentPersistent
                                                Hard disk 7    
                                                Hard disk 8    
                                                Hard disk 10   
171_A92SV096    192.168.1.5         PoweredOn   Hard disk 5    IndependentPersistent
                                                Hard disk 10
```

[image]

Please let me know what changes I need to make in the code.

Comment: It is not clear if you looking for empty cells in the `Name`, `Server`, `PowerState` and `DiskMode` columns (if the previous row is equal) or multi-line cells in the `Disk` column. As in that case: the `csv` format doesn't support multi-line cells.

Comment: That would mean grouping on the `Name`, `PowerState` and `DiskMode` properties, because DiskMode can have [different values](http://mvsourcecode.com/vmware-independent-persistent-vs-independent-non-persistent-disk-mode-mvsourcecode/)

Comment: Do you want the literal output text you’ve shown to be saved into your output file, or have you opened the ```*.csv``` file in Excel and that’s what the spreadsheet looks like? You’re using ```Export-Csv``` in your code which doesn’t really match your desired output…

Comment: @Theo: Yes. that is exactly. even I tried finding some solution in excel but no luck.

Comment: @iRon: The `Disk` column can have multiple values as you can see in sample. but other columns are having same values. so want to display `Name`, `Server`, `PowerState` and `DiskMode` only once per `Name`

Comment: The sample in the question is a display output and doesn't reveal how the `csv` is actually build up. Please, add that `cvs` sample  as bare text [to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72785259/edit).

Comment: @iRon: The first output sample is the current csv data which I am getting. added the snaphot for your reference

Comment: This is an excel view but you asking for a `csv` file, or?. Try to setup what you want as a result in Excel, then `file`-->`export` that to a `csv` file, confirm that you are able to correctly import the `csv` file back in (as said, the `csv` format is limited in what you trying to do) and put the contents (e.g. open it with `NotePad.exe`) of the `csv` in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the csv file you created with your code, you can use that as a basis to get the output you need like this:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\VMInfo.csv'
# first group the data on the Name property
$data | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    # next, group that on property PowerState
    foreach ($groupPowerState in ($_.Group | Group-Object PowerState)) {
        $powerState = $groupPowerState.Name
        # finally, group that on property DiskMode
        foreach ($groupDiskMode in ($groupPowerState.Group | Group-Object DiskMode)) {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Name       = $name
                Server     = $groupDiskMode.Group[0].Server
                PowerState = $powerState
                Disk       = $groupDiskMode.Group.Disk -join [environment]::NewLine
                DiskMode   = $groupDiskMode.Name

            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\GroupedVMInfo.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

This should give you a new CSV file you can double-click to open in Excel

Using your example data this would open in Excel as:

[image]

---

Of course, you don't need to write the report out to CSV and then read it back in if you would capture the output in variable `$data` like this:

```
$data = foreach ($myVM in $myVMs) {
    $VMDKs = $myVM | Get-HardDisk
    $VMDISKMode = $myVM
    foreach ($VMDK in $VMDKs) {
        if ($VMDK -ne $null) {
            $Diskmode = $VMDK.Persistence
            if($Diskmode -ne 'Persistent') {
                [PSCustomObject] @{
                    Name       = $myVM.name
                    Server     = $vc
                    PowerState = $myVM.PowerState
                    Disk       = $VMDK.Name
                    DiskMode   = $VMDK.Persistence
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```